# How PowerShell does decide which mode when parsing?

Tags: powershell, variables

I can't quite understand how PowerShell parses commands and need your help.

I read the following explanation by Microsoft's [about_parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-6) documentation:

> When processing a command, the PowerShell parser operates in expression mode or in argument mode:
>
> In expression mode, character string values must be contained in quotation marks. Numbers not enclosed in quotation marks are treated as numerical values (rather than as a series of characters).
>
> In argument mode, each value is treated as an expandable string unless it begins with one of the following special characters: dollar sign ($), at sign (@), single quotation mark ('), double quotation mark ("), or an opening parenthesis (().
>
> If preceded by one of these characters, the value is treated as a value expression.

I can understand when parsing a command, PowerShell uses either expression mode or argument mode, but I can't quite understand the following examples.

```
$a = 2+2
Write-Output $a #4(int), expression mode
Write-Output $a/H #4/H(str), argument mode
```

I wonder PowerShell expands variable first and then decide which mode when parsing, but is it right?

If so, there's another question about data type.

It seems reasonable for me the former command produces integral, but the latter one doesn't. Why can integer `4` be put next to string `/H`?

I tried this example and it worked. It seems variables turn into string whatever data type they are when expanded. Is it right?

```
$b = 100
Add-Content C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\$b\test.txt 'test'
```

I appreciate for your help.

**Edited to clarify the point after got the comment**

I've got the comment that the both Write-Output examples are argument mode, so can the examples be interpreted like this?

> Write-Output "$a"
>
> Write-Output "$a/H"

I'm terribly sorry for too ambiguous question, but I want to know:

1. In argument mode, double quotations are omitted?
2. The Write-Output examples are quoted from microsoft's document I linked and it says the first example produces integral, but is it wrong?

Comment: Both of your `Write-Output` examples are argument mode.

Comment: If your statement is a command, it's argument mode.  `& my.exe`, `Get-Something`, etc. are all argument mode.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Thank you for your mention. I edited the question reflencting your comment.